# jdbc driver is not loading in apache jmeter using jmeter.properties file

Tags: java, jdbc, jar, jmeter

I have apache jmeter based test tool, Previously I had Sybase database to connect from test tool which has easily connected using "**jconn3-6.0-b26564.jar**" and I am defining it in the jmeter.properties

***user.classpath=../../jar/sybase/jconn3-6.0-b26564.jar***

while running my testtool it .jar used to load and I used to connect to the sybase database.

Now, my requirement got changed and I have to connect my application to the **ORACLE 11G** database, in the testtool package I have **/jar** folder under that I have oracle jar i.e. **ojdbc14.jar**, which is compatible while connecting to the oracle database, I have tried it by using eclips. My actual problem is here, in **jmeter.properties** file I don't have by default oracle jar path added only sybase is there. I tried adding manually and restarted **apache** but it is not picking up the ojdbc14.jar and I am getting below error in my testtool log:

***FATAL DatabaseOperations:51 - Exception oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver***

so my all test cases are failing as I am not able to connect to database. is there any alternate way where I can load my jdbc jar. Please help.

Note: I don't have code access so I can't change anything in code.

Comment: Show us what you use for the path in your jmeter.properties for the ojdbc14.jar then.

Comment: user.classpath=../../jar/oracle/ojdbc14.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer for my question. I have copied the ojdbc14.jar in /lib under the jmeter  and restarted the apache it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using full path instead of relative. If it solves your issue - check the relative path.
2. Make sure that *user.classpath* property isn't getting overriden via *user.properties* file or command-line arguments
3. As the last resort you can drop Oracle JDBC driver to /lib folder of your JMeter installation
4. JMeter restart is required to reload classpath changes.
5. You can add additional files and folders to classpath at [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level.

See:

- [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Also I believe you need to use more "fresh" client JDBC library for Oracle 11, I would recommend downloading [ojdbc6.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html) which is designed to work with Java 6 instead of ojdbc4.jar which is for Java 1.4.